# What Boot Option should I choose

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation

I want to Install Ubuntu on a system that already comes with a factory fitted Windows 8, I would like to keep both OS's running together.

When I click F9 on startup I have two options for booting using USB

option 1: USD Hard Drive (UEFI) - Generic Flash Disk

option 2: USD Hard Drive - Generic Flash Disk

Let me note I tried using option 2 but I had problems booting Ubuntu, grub wasn't coming up on startup so Windows was automatically loading when I put on the system.

Comment: Option 1 safer and widely used.

Comment: Okay, guess that was why dual booting wasn't working on startup. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `option 1` as 
`UEFI` offers many useful features like secure boot which can prevent boot-time viruses from loading. Thus it is recommended to install any operating system in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 1):

The Best secure way is in UEFI mode. It is better to leave secure boot off (depends on your preference) if you want to install 3rd parties codecs and drivers which are usually unsigned.